# TexLive 2011 uses 2010 version

Tags: installing, texlive

I have updated my TexLive distribution from 2010 to 2011. But when I run `pdflatex` it still uses the older 2010 version. How can I change this? Also when I use `tex --v` it only shows the old version: TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2010).

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Comment: I'm running on a Mac.

Comment: @Henry Did you install MacTeX 2011 or 'vanilla' TeX Live. On the Mac, MacTeX is usually the best choice.

Comment: I'm using MacTeX.

Comment: I am not a Mac user, but probably the 2010's pdflatex is higher on the search path. A symlink or something similar should solve the problem. Uninstalling 2010 wouldn't harm too.

Comment: I reinstalled MacTeX and it's working now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

On the mac, you need to go the menu Apple > Pref System > Distribution TeX and the you can make a choice between TeXlive 2010 or TeXLive 2011.

You can verify your installation : in the finder go to folder (shift apple G) then /usr/local/texlive/  you can see 2010 and 2011.

You verify your Path with in the terminal $echo $PATH.

For me : /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbin

You can also verify if `/usr/texbin` is a link through 2011